# on click event not getting the value of textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In each row there is a textbox and a button i want to get the textdata to on click of button by their respective textbox. but problam is i am getting the same value for each button click because textboxID is same ... in loop 
my code is like that ...is there any way to get the value of each textbox for diff button click

```
 <% @obj.each_with_index do |time_sheet, i| %>
   <tr>
     <td style="width:30px;"><input type="text" name="comment"  id='commentId'></td>
     <td class="table-styling"> <button type="button" id="waiver">Waiver</button></td>
   </tr>
  <% end %>


  $('#waiver').live("click", function() {
 var commentVal = $("#commentId").val();
 alert(commentVal); //getting same value for each button click

   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#waiver', function() {
   var commentVal = $(this).closest('tr').find("#commentId").val();
   console.log(commentVal);
});
```

of course, ID's are unique, and it looks like you are mass producing elements with the same ID inside a loop, which is not a good idea, and makes the javascript go boo-boo.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating tons of elements that have the same `id` attribute. The `id` attribute is used to identify *one* element. No more.

Use a class instead:

```
<% @obj.each_with_index do |time_sheet, i| %>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 30px;">
            <input type="text" name="comment" class="comment" />
        </td>

        <td class="table-styling">
            <button type="button" class="waiver">Waiver</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

And your JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.waiver', function() {
    var commentVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('.comment').val();
});
```

Comment: How exactly do you find an input inside a button?

Comment: @adeneo: Magic ;) Thanks, I completely missed that.

Comment: Is that the jQuery version of sorcery, and if so, where can I get it?

Comment: @Blender: Plugin page not found at GitHub :(

Answer (score 3):

The first important thing is ID should be Unique!

If you want to get the respective text box value, you can try **replace your code with class name instead of id** shown below

```
<% @obj.each_with_index do |time_sheet, i| %>
 <tr>
 <td style="width:30px;">
   <input type="text" name="comment"  class='comment-textbox'>    </td>
 <td class="table-styling"> 
   <button type="button" class="btn-waiver">Waiver</button></td>
 </tr>
```

```
 $('.btn-waiver').live("click", function() {
 var commentVal =$(this).closest('tr').find('.comment-textbox').val();
     //or
 var commentVal = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('.comment-textbox').val();
 alert(commentVal); //getting same value for each button click

 });
```